# What is the proper way to construct class, object in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, class, subclass

If I have multiple Class like class Page, class Page1, class Page2 that need to use the same Element class. In order to get self.driver to use on ELement class, I will need to duplicate lots of code from `class Ele(e)` to `class itemWrap` on each `class Page` to pass `self.driver` as input. What is the best way for me to construct the following code?

```
# elements.py
class Element(object):

    def addItem(self, owner=None):
        for _i in owner:
            options = self.findAvaItem()
            i = options.index(_i)
            self.ele.find_element_by_xpath('{}/{}'.format(self.l, i)).click()

    def delItem(self, owner=None):
        for _i in owner:
            options = self.findSelecItem()
            i = options.index(_i)
            self.ele.find_element_by_xpath('{}/{}'.format(self.l, i)).click()

    def findAvaItem(self):
        _o = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css==div.menu.transition.visible').text
        return _o.split('\n')

    def findSelecItem(self):
        _o = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css==a.ui.label')
        return [i.text for i in _o]

# BasePage.py
class BasePage(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

# Page.py
from elements import Element as e

class Ele(e):
    def __init__(self, driver, _t):
        self.driver = driver
        self.l = 'element l variable'
        self.t = _t

class itemWrap(object):

    def __init__(self, driver, _type):
        self.ele = Ele(driver, _type)
        self.driver = driver
        self.t = _type

    def sel_item(self, _value):
        self.ele.addItem(_value)

    def desel_item(self, _value):
        self.ele.delItem(_value)

class Page(BasePage):
    def inputItem(self, _type, _value):
        itemWrap(self.driver, _type).sel_item(_value)

    def removeItem(self, _type, _value):
        itemWrap(self.driver, _type).desel_item(_value)

# Test.py
from Page import Page
from selenium import webdriver as WebDriver

class Test(object):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        if hasattr(super(Test, cls), 'setup_class'):
            super(Test, cls).setup_class()
        cls.driver = WebDriver(desired_capabilities=chrome, command_executor='127.0.0.1')

    def check_function(self):
        self.Page.inputItem('typeA', ['item A1', 'item A2', 'item A3'])
        self.Page.removeItem('typeA', ['item A1', 'item A2', 'item A3'])
        self.Page.inputItem('typeB', ['item B1', 'item B2'])
        self.Page.removeItem('typeB', ['item B1', 'item B2'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to build a facade layer in your `itemWrap` class such that each method of `itemWrap` just passes along a call to `self.ele`. Is this correct?

If so, you can generate the functions on the fly. (You could do more automated stuff if there was a consistent text pattern in the wrap-method vs. element-method names. As is, you'll have to provide a dict.)

```
class Ele:
    def addItem(self, x):
        print("Additem",x)
    def delItem(self, x):
        print("DelItem",x)

class ItemWrap:
    def __init__(self, ele):
        self.ele = ele

    method_map = {
        'sel_item': 'addItem',
        'desel_item': 'delItem',
        # more methods go here
    }

for myname, elname in ItemWrap.method_map.items():
    msrc = "def {}(self, _value):\n" \
           "    return self.ele.{}(_value)\n".format(myname, elname)
    gbls = {}
    exec(msrc, gbls)
    setattr(ItemWrap, myname, gbls[myname])

e = Ele()
i = ItemWrap(e)
i.sel_item(10)
i.desel_item(11)
```